# Why does SQLite full-text search (FTS4) treat angle brackets differently in a compound search?

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, fts3, fts4

I have an SQLite database using FTS4. It is used to store emails with message id's of the form:

Searching for messages using the FTS MATCH syntax, I get a result from:

```
SELECT rowid FROM emails WHERE emails MATCH '<8200@comms.io>'
```

This returns the correct row. But when I try to find multiple emails, I get an empty response:

```
SELECT rowid FROM emails WHERE emails MATCH '<8200@comms.io> OR <8188@comms.io>'
```

Strangely though, I can search without the angle bracket characters. This returns both rows:

```
SELECT rowid FROM emails WHERE emails MATCH '8200@comms.io OR 8188@comms.io'
```

This even though the angle brackets are present in the stored columns. I can find no mention that these are special characters in SQLite, and without the 'OR', the single-term search works fine.

Why are these characters treated differently in my compound search?

Comment: Which [tokenizer](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#tokenizer) are you using?

Comment: This is with the default tokenizer.

Answer (score 2):

The default (`simple`) tokenizer reads alphanumerical characters and treats all others as word separators to be ignored.
So when searching for a message ID, you have to actually search for a phrase with multiple words (`8200`, `comms`, and `io`).

If you want to treat the entire message ID as a word, you have to write a [custom tokenizer](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_8_1).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards the tokenizer: according to http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#tokenizer, unicode characters under 128 (<,>,@) are discarded. So possibly my search is transforming to '8200 AND comms AND io'. But this would happen in both cases, with the low-precedence OR in the compound search. So that should produce a result equivalent to '( 8200 AND comms AND io) OR ( 8188 AND comms AND io)', but nothing is returned.

Comment: This is not strictly true. There is an undocumented feature in the simple tokenizer which allows the delimiters to be customized. I posted a question about this to the [SQLite mailing list](http://sqlite.org:8080/cgi-bin/mailman/private/sqlite-users/2014-September/055419.html).